# Custom views (or routes) in FOSRestController

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am using FOSRest Bundle to implement Rest API's.

I have the function getTermsAction() which returns all the terms from the DB.

I have a template listTerms.html.twig which shows the list of terms.

I want to implement another function listTermsAction() which will render this template and return it.

Something like this (I added this to my controller)

```
/**
      * @Route("/listTerms",name="listTerms")
      */
    public function listTermsAction()
    {
      $view = $this->view(null,200)
              ->setTemplate("TermsBundle:Default:listTerms.html.twig");
      return $this->handleView($view);

    }
```

I tried to this by adding the following code in routing.yml file

```
list_terms:
    pattern:  /terms/listTerms
    defaults: {_controller:TermsBundle:Terms:listTermsAction}
```

But it doesn't work!

It just shows me "null" in the browser

Answer (score 0):

The Solution i have given works but that snippet should be above the rest route in my routing.yml

That is routing.yml should be like

```
list_term:
    pattern:  /terms/listTerms
    defaults: {_controller:TermsBundle:Terms:listTerms}


terms:
    resource: Madhuri\TermsBundle\Controller\TermsController
    type: rest
    prefix: /
```

`list_term route` should be above `terms route`